# Logarithmic derivative of Dirichlet series and relation to Mangoldt function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function#Dirichlet_series), the following formula is given:

$$\frac {F^\prime(s)}{F(s)} = - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)\Lambda(n)}{n^s}$$

I understand the proof for the zeta-function, but not for the Dirichlet Series of a multiplicative function. I have to proof this formula especially for the $L$-function of modular forms and tried to do so with the Euler product but have not managed it yet.

Comment: This isn't true for an arbitrary multiplicative function; it's only true for *completely* multiplicative functions. For the $L$-function of a modular form, the statement is not correct (though the actually expression is not completely dissimilar).

Comment: I see, my mistake. But I found pretty much the same statement for modular forms [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03114) on page 4, Lemma 2.2. And $\Lambda_f(n)$ is, if I am not mistaken, $\lambda_f(n) \Lambda(n)$, with $\lambda_f(n)$ being the coefficients of the modular form $f$. This is also stated in "Analytic Number Theory" by H.Iwaniec and E.Kowalski.

Comment: Your mistake is the fact that $\Lambda_f(n)$ is *not* equal to $\lambda_f(n) \Lambda(n)$; they agree on primes, but not on prime powers.

Comment: For a newform the Euler factors are inverse of polynomials of degree $\le 1$ thus factoring them gives $F(s) = F_1(s)F_2(s)$ with the coefficients of $F_1,F_2$ completely multiplicative so that $F'(s)/F(s) = -\sum_{p^k} \log(p) (a_p(F_1)^k+a_p(F_2)^k)p^{-sk}$. An eigenform will be of the form $F(s)\prod_{p | N} G_p(p^{-s})$ with $G_p$ some polynomials and $F$ a newform.